# class clashes with package of same name when using Glide

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use `Glide` on my app. `Glide` needs me to create a class that extends `Application` then inside that I need to create a method that extends `AppGlideModule`. Then I need to do a `Make Project` which I did. For some reason, `Glide` creates multiple instances of the `Application` class causing an error.

What I did was rename the `Application` class several times, move the class on a different folder but the error is still the same. After moving the `Application` class on a different folder, `Android Studio` detects 2 instance of the class. 1 instance that is outside the folder and another that is inside the folder. Note that the `Application` class is already inside the folder and no other class got the same name as that class.

This my `Application` class.

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

public class Globals extends Application {

    @GlideModule
    public final class mAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle(app).

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
}
```

This is the error that keeps appearing.

```
error: class Globals clashes with package of same name
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in gradle

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
```

and try to change the name of class from `Globals` to `Application`and add the class name in `application` tag of manifest file

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Comment: I'm already using `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'`. Do I need to downgrade for it to work? I've already included `Globals` on my manifest too.

Comment: you donot need to downgrade. Thats the gradle version i am using in my project.

Comment: but why are you using 
 @GlideModule
    public final class mAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    }
i havent used this in my project

Comment: You need to use that so Glide can create GlideApp. I used to do that same thing of not creating that class. But now I already forgot how to use Glide and I saw I need that [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library)